# Changing IMAP port for Dovecot

Tags: port, imap, dovecot

I'm running Dovecot to let people access their email on my server. Unfortunately, some are on networks where they can't connect on the normal IMAP port, so I'm trying to change it. I changed the config to contain:

```
protocol imap {
  listen = *.1433 *.143
  ...
```

Then dovecot fails to restart:

```
Fatal: listen: Can't resolve address *.1433: Name or service not known
```

What's the correct way of doing this? If possible, I'd prefer to have it listening on both ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my FC10 system running `dovecot-1.1.10-1.fc10` the syntax is:

```
protocol imap {
    listen = *:9999 *:143
    ....
}
```

Look to see what error is being reported.  If the configuration is actually correct then the most likely is 'Address already in use', meaning that some other process is already listening on port 9999.

EDIT - I see you've amended the question.  The error is that you're using a '.' instead of a ':' as the port separator.

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: It should be a colon, not a "."

Comment: Changing it to a colon helped. It works now

Answer (score 3):

I did a little research, accourding to the [FAQ](http://wiki.dovecot.org/QuestionsAndAnswers#Is_it_possible_to_have_Dovecot_imap.2BAC8-pop_daemons_listening_on_multiple_ports.3F)

> Is it possible to have Dovecot
>   imap/pop daemons listening on multiple
>   ports?
>
> No, not in the current stable release.
>   But there are workarounds, eg using
>   your firewall to redirect incoming
>   traffic to a given port.

You can simply use iptables to redirect connections to 9999 to 143 with a command like below.

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9999 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 143
```

Comment: iptables is awesome like that.

Comment: strange, the multiple port syntax in my answer seems to work fine.

Comment: @Alnitak,  I used your syntax on my system and dovecot started, but netstat only showed it listening on one port. (deb5.0)

Comment: Having Dovecot listen to multiple ports for the same service is possible since version 1.1. Debian Lenny only ships Dovecot 1.0.x.

Answer (score 2):

With a current (2015) Dovecot version, the configuration for a different port or multiple ports is now different. You add a `inet_listener ... {}` section for each port. On my Debian 8 (Jessie) system, it is in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf`:

```
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    #port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imap_9143 {
    port = 9143
  }
  inet_listener imap_whatever {
    port = 54321
  }
}
```

If it's in another file on your system, you can find it with `grep -r -l 'inet_listener imap' /etc`.

Comment: Seems to work on Debian Buster / 10.7 too!